# Form blade, can't understand translating from blade to html

Tags: laravel

**I have this form in blade:**

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => ['SearchController@searchUser'], 'method' => 'GET']) }}
    {{ Form::text('q', '', ['id' =>  'q', 'placeholder' =>  'Enter name'])}}
    {{ Form::submit('Search', array('class' => 'button expand')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**How can I translate it into html?**

Comment: What do you mean with translate into HTML? this only render HTML code if you have your laravel on a server (Apache o Nginx)

Comment: But how should I set up to show it, it shows me error when displaying?

Comment: is it displaying an error? What is the error?

Comment: Class form not found, I read somewhere that I need something as facade or dunno?

Comment: I think you need this https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.2, latest one

Comment: user3158900, Yeah your solution is the right way to do this, thank you, it displays fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Laravel 5.2, you must install HTML and Form as module.

follow these steps and it must be rendered your code:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Laravel and feel its confusing with all those syntax you can use normal HTML that you already know. Its not a compulsion to use Laravel's blade shortcut.So something like

```
<form action="SearchController@searchUser" method="get">
//All your inputs
</form>
```

And to use form in your project you have to get a facade. You can follow the tutorial below :
http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/09/creating-a-contact-form-in-laravel-5-using-the-form-request-feature/